# meteorjs run js before rendering

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is it possible to execute a javascript script before templates will be rendered ?

I **dont** want to do it with **iron-router** - if possible.

In my project there is a script which translate a few words in the template. These translations have to be read out of a file so there is a delay before the right output is there. I now want to read the whole file at the beginning and save it in the cache. After saving this the template gets the right words.

Then i want to complete the Template rendering.

Something like this:

```
// Client only
Handlebars.registerHelper('translate', function(stringPart) {
   return 'translated String'; // this string comes from function "prepareTranslate" which saves the values
});

var prepareTranslate = function(){
   [...]
   // preparing completed:
   Meteor.renderCurrTemplates();
}();
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but did you consider using an [internationalization package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/just-i18n)?

Comment: I dont want to use a existing package to translate my text. I try to write my own package for me and also for my school-project.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would just be to prevent the individual template(s) from being rendered until your translations are ready with an `{{#if}}` block:

```html
<body>
  {{#if translationsReady}}
    {{> yourTemplate}}
  {{/if}}
</body>
```

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  UI.registerHelper("translationsReady", function() {
    return !!Session.get("translations");
  });

  UI.registerHelper("translate", function(key) {
    return Session.get("translations")[key];
  });

  // assuming your translations are coming from a Meteor.call:
  Meteor.call("translations", "en-US", function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
      Session.set("translations", result);
    }
  });
}
```

This uses `Session`. You could also use a local `Meteor.Collection` or your own `Deps.Dependency` object if that better fits your needs.

Comment: This is a nice idea! Thanks for the aolution. I will play a bit around with this - but this is not the solution i want to use in my case. I shpuld write it in the question ... the best solution i am looking for is that i dont have to write my own template helper for each template ... the best solution i am imagin is that i can write it globaly so a person is able to download and use my package without editing every template with a "wait for it"-Handler.

Comment: If your package prevents initial loading of templates globally I don't think developers using it will be very happy ;) - that's a bit of a UX nightmare. Anyway, both of the helper functions I showed are global helpers - `UI.registerHelper` is the new replacement for `Handlebars.registerHelper`. So both the `translationsReady` and `translate` helpers will be global helpers.

Comment: But it isnt uncommon to wait for rendering a template for a specific state - e.g. a subscription of a collection. So in my way it is important for the templates to wait for a finished translation before rendering. I can not belive that there isnt a way to define this globaly - for example (but in my eyes not the best way): Router.waitGlobalyFor = function () { // translate ...  return true;};